# MVC VS Template with Authorization: When is the database file created?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

The template comes without database at first. When I launch the application some code must create the db obviously, because  I check the appData folder and now it's there.
Can you tell me which part of the code creates it? Thanks. I have long looked at the code and I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only answer possible is that entity framework creates the database automatically. But the strange thing is if I remove thee database it does not get recreated, I get an error that says it's missing it.